# Beautiful Soup find.all() that accepts start of word

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm web scraping a site with beautiful soup that has class names like the following:

`<a class="Component-headline-0-2-109" data-key="card-headline" href="/article/politics-senate-elections-legislation-coronavirus-pandemic-bills-f100b3a3b4498a75d6ce522dc09056b0">`

The primary issue is that the class name always starts with `Component-headline-` but just send with a random number. When I use beautiful soup's `soup.find_all('class','Component-headline')`, it's not able to grab anything because of the unique number. Is it possible to use find_all, but to grab all the classes that just start with "Component-headline"?

I was also thinking on using the `data-key="card-headline"`, and use `soup.find_all('data-key','card-headline')`, but for some reason that didn't work either, so I assume I can't find by data-key, but not sure. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup supports regex, so you can use `re.compile` to search for partial text on the class attribute

```
import re 
soup.find_all('a', class_=re.compile('Component-headline'))
```

You can also use `lambda`

```
soup.find_all('a', class_=lambda c: c.startswith('Component-headline'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [`[attribute^=value]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) CSS Selector.

To use a CSS Selector, instead of the `find_all()` method, use [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

The following selects all classes that start with `Component-headline`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.select('[class^="Component-headline"]'))
```